# sql query against redshift data

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have the following table in redshift:

```
ID, Category
flinch, cat
flinch, cat
mara, dog
mara, cat
```

the aim here is to get for each ID the number of occurences of each category , hence the expected resut would be:

```
ID,Category,size
flinch, cat, 2
mara, dog, 1
mara, cat, 1
```

I tried several queries but got  exceptions :`ERROR: could not identify an ordering operator for type record Hint: Use an explicit ordering operator or modify the query.`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `group by`:

```
select id, category, count(*) as size
from t
group by id, category;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this one?

```
select id, category, count(*)
from mytable
group by id, category
```